# Proof of weak stationary random process autocovariance always goes to zero?

Tags: random-process, covariance, proof, stationary

Professor told me that if a random process is weak stationary, and it does not feature any periodic component, then its autocovariance always goes to zero.

I can intuitively understand it, however, where can I find the formal proof of such property?

Comment: What about a process such that every $X(t)$ is the same random variable? In that case the autocovariance function would be a non-zero constant, but the process is WSS.

Comment: Hi Tendero: I don't want to get into a big dicussion but, in statistical time-series/econometrics, one would say that  auto-covariance is not defined because process has zero variance. But I'm well aware that, in DSP, things can be quite different. All the best.

Comment: @Giovanni Castellano: I don't know if what your professor is saying is true but chapter 4 of this document would probably be pretty enlightening if you have the time to check it out. good luck. oh, the answer may also be in brockwell and davis but I can't find that text right now. https://www.stat.tamu.edu/~suhasini/teaching673/time_series.pdf

Comment: @Tendero The _autocorrelation_ function converges to the square of the mean while the _autocovariance_ function does converge to 0 as $\tau$ increases without bound. No problems whatsoever even in the case of your proposed counterexample.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate: : I'm pretty sure the OP's professor assumes a de-meaned process  Can you point to somewhere that shows that acf converges to the square of the mean asymptotically. I looked and couldn't find it.  I'm not concerned with counter-example bur rather talking about the general case. Thanks.

Comment: NB: If the process it not zero mean, its autocorrelation need not converge at all. Counter-example: $\sum_n b_n \cdot {\rm rect}(t-n)$ where $b_n \in \{0,1\}$. Its ACF contains a periodic component, though the original process is not periodic. We learned: "*if* the ACF converges, then its limit is the squared mean". Can't tell anymore which textbook this was based on.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I may be making a mistake somewhere, but if we calculate $\gamma_s=E[(X_t-\mu)(X_{t-s}-\mu)]$ where every $X_t$ is the same finite, non-zero variance random variable, isn't $\gamma_s$ a non-zero constant?

Comment: @Tendero: There's a contraction there because if the process has non-zero variance then it's not a process where every random variable, $X((t)$ is the same. For that to be true, it would have toe zero variance process and then, as I said, atleast in statistical time -series, the covariance is not defined...

Comment: @markleeds I was thinking of a process such that all its values depend on a single realization of a unique random variable. For example, let $X$ be random variable that represents the outcome of a 6-faced dice. The process is defined such that $Y(t)=X$. So you throw the dice once, and the process then shows that value for any $t$. But then $$\gamma_s=E[(Y_t-\mu)(Y_{t-s}-\mu)]=E[(X-3.5)^2]$$ and that is not zero, yet constant.

Comment: @Tendero: interesting but definitely a bit strange because you're saying that one outcome determines all the outcomes over all t. I agree that it's not zero but I never heard of a process like that where one realization of an RV determines the whole stochastic process.

Comment: @Tendero: I get  more clearly what you're doing by using the 3.5 mean. You're saying that the dice roll is "part of" the stochastic process so we can't say that the mean is the appearing face. Definitely an interesting process. I think you may have constructed a process that is not ergodic. I always wondered what  would be  a not ergodic process  and yours may be one because the mean of many short (in time) repetitions of the process would not converge to the mean of one long (in time) sample of the process. I'm not sure what happens with a not-ergodic process as far as asymptotic covariance.

Comment: @markleeds I agree with you on the ergodicity of the process. This is why I proposed this (rather absurd) process as a counterexample to the OP's question. I think one has to assume further things to state that the autocovariance of a WSS process always tends to zero.

Comment: @Tendero: it's a nice non-ergodic example but I think ergodicity is generally always assumed. I still can't find a proof of the statement anywhere ? thanks for example. I always wondered what an example of a non-ergodic time-series would be.